# Complete HTML with stange characters

Tags: php, html, special-characters

I use this function to complete my HTML.

```
function correct_html($string) {
    $dom = new \DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($string);

    $mock = new \DOMDocument;
    $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    foreach ($body->childNodes as $child) {
        $mock->appendChild($mock->importNode($child, true));
    }

    return trim($mock->saveHTML());
}
```

But when i use this function with an é or any other special characters it's giving me Ã©. How can i fix this

Comment: `$dom->encoding = 'utf-8'` add this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

> utf8_decode()

before parsing the string to the loadHTML(), like this,

```
function correct_html($string) {
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($string));

    $mock = new \DOMDocument;
    $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
    foreach ($body->childNodes as $child) {
        $mock->appendChild($mock->importNode($child, true));
    }

    return trim($mock->saveHTML());
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped you @StanvanHeertum

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add encoding to the construct of [DOMDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```

Also make sure you set the Encoding in the headers.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help it. It's still giving me Ã© back when I type é